# Facebook Like social plugin sizing issues

Tags: css, facebook, plugins

I am using the Facebook Like social plugin on my website, and every time the page loads, the plugin stretches the height of the div it is in until the plugin has loaded.

I did define the height of the div that the social plugin is in, but even though the height stayed the same, you could still see the shift. I am also using the Twitter and Google plus social plugins - this makes the shift more noticeable since they get shifted also (shift under the h3 heading).

.socialBookmarks {margin:30px 0;padding:5px 15px;overflow:hidden;}

.socialBookmarks .social-wrap
   {display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}

.social-wrap .ezimageBox {float:left}

```
<div class="socialBookmarks">

   <h3 class="inline-block">Share:</h3>

      <div class="social-wrap clearfix">

         <div class="ezimageBox">
         (loads twitter social plugin)
         </div>

        <div class="ezimageBox">
        (loads google plus social plugin
        </div>

        <div class="ezimageBox">
        (loads facebook social plugin)      
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to work around this problem? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the width and height of the wrapping `<div>` (in your case, .ezimageBox) usually does the trick for me.

Try this:

```
.social-wrap .ezimageBox {float:left, width:100px, height: 20px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Does it still flicker?